# How do I automatically check the autorenewal option by default on a membership contribution page?

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, recurring-contributions, auto-renew, condition

We're running on Drupal 7.69 and Civi 5.13.x.

Is there a way to have the option to autorenew ticked by default through configuration?

See image below:
[image]

Comment: So you always want the General membership to auto-renew? Or just check box on initial load and than let user un-select it if they wont like to auto-renew?

Comment: This one Pradeep - "just check box on initial load and than let user un-select it if they wont like to auto-renew".

Answer (score 2):

For a site using CiviCRM profiles you can opt to use Joinery's [Profile Conditionals extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals) and adapt the conditions to which you want this behavior to occur.

For it be checked with any price field selected, an example is below:

```
<?php
        
$civicrm_setting['com.joineryhq.profcond']['com.joineryhq.profcond']['contribution']['all'] = array(
          '01_auto_renew_is_checked' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
              'all_of' => array(
                array(
                  'selector' => 'input[name="price_7"]',
                    'op' => 'is_checked',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                'states' => array (
                  'pass' => array (
                    'selectors'  => array(
                      'input#auto_renew[type="checkbox"]' => array (
                        'properties' => array('checked' => TRUE),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  'fail' => array (
                    'selectors'  => array(
                      'input#auto_renew[type="checkbox"]' => array (
                        'properties' => array('checked' => FALSE),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Change out the price field (price_7) with yours. There are many ways to change the conditions based on your use case, you can find instructions on those options [here](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.profcond?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration).

I put this in it's own `profcond.settings.php` file in case you make a syntax error and want to quickly deactivate the conditionals to prevent it from breaking CiviCRM. Add `include __DIR__ . '/profcond.settings.php';` to `civicrm.settings.php` file for this setup.

Also noting that recently there was a change in core that displays / unchecks the "Please renew my membership automatically" option when selecting a price option so using the "onload" option exclusively no longer works (tested 5.65 where that last worked).

Answer (score 1):

Unless things have changed I believe this requires a customisation. We did one a while back. I will check what effort is involved in getting it extracted in to an extension if there is not one 'out there'.

Comment: Hmm looks like the work we did doesn't properly deal with switching between Pay Later and CC. We could get this sorted if you are interested. PM me if you want an estimate. Don't expect it will take much